# oracle 000923:from keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle

```
MERGE INTO stg_ta_payroll
    USING
    (select :NEW.ID_TM_ENR ID_TM_ENR, to_number(:NEW.ID_STR_RT) ID_STR_RT, :NEW.ID_EM ID_EM,
    nvl(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(:NEW.TS_EM_TM_IN,'YYMMDD')),0) V_TA_DATE,
    V_SESSION_NO V_SESSION_NO,
    :NEW.TS_EM_TM_IN TS_EM_TM_IN, :NEW.TS_EM_TM_OUT TS_EM_TM_OUT,
        DECODE(:NEW.TY_TM,'0',nvl(to_char(:NEW.TS_EM_TM_IN,'HH24MI'),'0000'),' ') V_TIME_IN,
        DECODE(:NEW.TY_TM,'0',nvl(to_char(:NEW.TS_EM_TM_OUT,'HH24MI'),'0000'),' ') V_TIME_OUT,
    V_MGR_OVRD V_MGR_OVRD,
    :NEW.ID_MGR ID_MGR,DECODE(:NEW.TY_TM,'XX','9',:NEW.TY_TM) TY_TM,
        DECODE(:NEW.TY_TM,'0',:NEW.OTHER_HRS_STR,(CASE WHEN ID_EM=:NEW.ID_EM AND nvl(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TS_EM_TM_IN,'YYMMDD')),0)=nvl(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(:NEW.TS_EM_TM_IN,'YYMMDD')),0) AND TY_TM=:NEW.TY_TM THEN SUM(:NEW.OTHER_HRS_STR) ELSE 0 END)) V_OTHER_HRS_STR
    V_AREA V_AREA, V_ASSC_NAME V_ASSC_NAME, V_MISC_WAGES_DESC V_MISC_WAGES_DESC, V_SHRT_STR_NAME V_SHRT_STR_NAME,
    (:NEW.HRS_STR + V_OTHER_HRS_STR) TOT_HRS from dual) STG
    ON (TIME_ENT_ID=STG.ID_TM_ENR AND to_number(STR_ID)=to_number(STG.ID_STR_RT))
```

I am getting 000923 from keyword not found error can any one please help.Thank You

Comment: You might spot the error immediately if you format your code properly

Comment: @CodeBird - the doubles are OK, just pointless - giving a column an alias that's the same as the table name. Doesn't really hurt, but extra typing, and makes it harder to read...

Comment: huh!!! Weird extra useless typing, I always thought `AS` is needed for aliasing. @AlexPoole

Comment: that's not given by me its the source code from my company have to make changes in that based on the requirement

Comment: @CodeBird - no, the `AS` is optional; you can see that [in the syntax diagram](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55229).

Comment: interesting, works in mysql too, thanks for the info @AlexPoole

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have three column names here

```
V_OTHER_HRS_STR V_AREA V_AREA,
```

Comment: Looks like `V_OTHER_HRS` is a column alias for the previous expression, so it's missing a comma before the first `V_AREA`? (Not sure why you'd bother having a column alias that is the same as the column name but that seems to be fairly common).

Comment: ya thanx,i missed a separator in between :)